# How to write data from stringstream to a file (CPP)

Tags: c++

I have one function which is an call back from a library it looks like follows:

```
void onCallBack(int date, const std::stringstream &data);
```

I want to write data received from a `data` variable to an physical file so i am doing this:

```
void onCallBack(int date, const std::stringstream &data)
{
    ofstream filePtr;
    filePtr.open("data.file", ios::app);

    string dataToWrite = data.str();
    filePtr << dataToWrite.c_str();

    filePtr.close();
}
```

call back `onCallBack` function gets called when ever there is an update in data and i want to write this updated data to the file.

problem is that data is `std::stringstream` type and it behaves like an file/buffer and and from this buffer i just want to read update data part for example:

In first call back `data` contains string
`this is first line`

and in second call back it contains:
`this is first line

this is second line`

In the first call of the call back function I write `this is first line` string to the file and in second call back I just want to write `this is second line` to file not the fist line again.

How can i extract only updated part of the `std::stringstream`.

`const std::stringstream &data` variable is constant and can't be modified or we can't use `tellg` or `sync`.

UPDATE/EDIT:
1. Sorry for c tag.
2. for using `read` we need to provide block size to read and i don't know the block size.
3. Can you provide an example of doing this using ios_base::xalloc, ios:base::iword, and ios_base::pword.
4. read is not a const but tellg is.
5. yes no one call `data.str("")`, it is an pure virtual function from lib, in my code i am not doing this.

Comment: Removed the 'C' tag since this clearly isn't C.

Comment: Why not use `read` instead of `str`, which, presumably removes the read characters from the buffer.

Comment: Fixed Grammar mistake in title.

Comment: you probably rather want to reset the stringstreams contents than to check for any possible unwritten data.

Comment: Using `ios_base::xalloc`, `ios:base::iword`, and `ios_base::pword`, you can store data (like the position) in a stream.

Comment: @Aleks - `read()` isn't a `const` member.

Comment: Does your code ensure no-one will reset the stringstream data, `data.str("")` etc.? Did you consider inheriting from the string stream buffer, hooking into `xsputn`, `overflow`, and/or whatever else may be required? (I haven't checked the details on this, hence no answer.)

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to remember how much you've read previously and then take only part of the string as appropriate. How you do that is up to you. You could modify your call back to pass some kind of state in:

```
void onCallBack(int date, const std::stringstream &data, std::string::size_type& state);
```

If it's part of an interface (unlikely given what you posted, but that is a good way to do callbacks in general) you can store that state as a private member variable.

If you don't care about being reentrant and the stream never shrinks you could do it as a quick hack using a `static` variable in this example, which is the easiest to show working here, but asking for trouble:

```
// What happens if you change the stringstream? 
// This is why you need to re-think the callback interface
static std::string::size_type state = 0;
string dataToWrite = data.str().substr(state);
state += dataToWrite.size();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i can't modify the call back prototype and your given solution does not work :(, I have tried adding `size_type` and `substr`. after some while 5 to 10 iterations `dataToWrite` becomes blank.

Comment: @psp1: This means that either nothing new is added to the stream, or the stream has shrunk in size (been reset?).

Comment: SO what would be the best solution for this, am banging my head on this for last 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

If you are **sure** the `stringstream` object is the same for each calls to your callback, you can do that:

```
filePtr << data.rdbuf() << std::flush;
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I've edited your answer to add markup for the code you included.

Comment: Yes it works. See: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bf3eb63dda2c8ca

Answer (score 0):

You could clear the file contents before writing to it by replacing `ios::app` with `ios::trunc`.

Obviously its not optimal to write the entire stream every time, but if you can't change the prototype or flush the stream and you don't know the size of the new data, then I this is the only way I can think of doing it..

Comment: No this can not be done, as at the end we are not getting the full file, file will be provided as stack FILO (pipe) to it will repeat only some part of the data.